# convert factor vector to numeric

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have a data.frame (df) with a column df$points as shown below  and I want to convert this column to numeric type.

df$points:

```
1,96E-02
1,96E-02
1,87E-02
5,12E-01
5,12E-01
-3,92E-01
7,75E-01
6,90E-02
-6,55E-02
4,08E-01
-1,45E-01
3,00E-01
1,16E-01
5,32E-01
1,63E-01
-5,67E-01
-1,63E-01
1,51E-01
-1,56E-01
```

pp <- as.numeric(df$points) but it produced NA.
pp <- as.numeric(levels(df$points))[df$points], this is also not working due to the repeated values in that column. Thank you for any idea!

Comment: You could use `as.numeric(sub(',', '.', df$points))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the `,` with `.` using `sub` and convert to "numeric"

```
df$points <- as.numeric(sub(',', '.', df$points))
```